# Buffer Distance from Edge

Tags: qgis

How do I create a buffer distance from the edge of the polygon in qgis? The buffer already created calculates the distance form the center of the polygon. For my analysis, I'll need a hint for calculating a buffer form the edge of the polygon.

Comment: The buffer operation *does* start at the edge of a polygon. You need to create a graphic to explain what you're asking.

Comment: You should be able to explode your ploygons to polylines and then doing a one sided buffer on the lines.

Comment: there is same question on [esri forum](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/85709) that can also help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afterward you got buffer layer, use the difference processing tool to produce the "buffer" from the edge of the polygon.

For this situation; where Input layer is 'buffer' and Difference layer is 'polygon2':

[image]

I got this "buffer from the edge":

[image]

Result is a polygon layer with a hole. By the way, distance calculated is always from the edges of the polygon (not from the center).